# plupload statechange even plupload.STARTED not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plupload

I am trying to make plupload work from the jsfiddle sample [jsfiddle-plupload](http://jsfiddle.net/wQW4w/72/)

but that is not working on my side, the statechange events if block is getting skipped below is code

```
function validClasses()
{
    datas=[];
                    $('#uids li').each(function() {
                        var data = { 
                            className: $(this).attr("id")
                        };
                        datas.push(data);
                     });
    if(datas.length>0)
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            alert('error');
            return false;
        }
}
         var uploadInitialized = false;
        function plupload(){ 

          var uploader = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
            runtimes: 'html5,html4',
            url: 'fileUpload.htm',
            max_file_size: '200mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            multiple_queues: true,
            multipart_params: {
                "name": $("#name").val()
            },
            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
                {
                title: "Image files",
                extensions: "jpg,gif,png,eps,jpeg,pdf,tiff,tif"},
            {
                title: "Zip files",
                extensions: "zip"}
            ],
            init: {
                StateChanged: function(up) {
                    if (!uploadInitialized && up.state == plupload.STARTED) {
                        if (!validClasses()) {
                            up.stop();
                        } else {
                            uploadInitialized = true;
                        }
                    }
                },
                BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {
                    up.settings.multipart_params = {'name': $('#name').val()}
                }
            }
        });
   }
```

please note that in jsfiddle sample, the upload is just stopped, that is i can upload without adding files again. Where as on my side, the start upload button is getting disappeard, the file is in list but buttons disappear. and i am getting the upload status in place of buttons, i want the buttons to be there if upload is stopped also. I means in StateChanged i directly wrote up.stop() and that is also not working. Anyone please help. Thanks.

Comment: if (!uploadInitialized && up.state == plupload.STARTED) its not entering that block and because of plupload.STARTED is undefined, as i checked using an alert. Any solution please.